# Unauthorized sequels to the Narnia books?

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis, sequel

By "unauthorized" I mean "not by [C. S. Lewis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._S._Lewis)."

For example, [Neil Gaiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gaiman) wrote a (lovely in my opinion) short story titled "The Problem of Susan," collected in his [*fragile things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_Things) short story and poems anthology that gives an alternative interpretation of the Narnia stories.

Can you suggest a definitive list of commercially published sequels, full length parodies (*a la* *Bored of the Rings* videlicet *The Lord of the Rings*), or explicit reinterpretations of (e.g. *Wicked: The Life and Times of the Wicked Witch of the West*, and *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*) [Narnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia) or C. S. Lewis' visitors there as of June 1st, 2015? (No need to cite [another story beginning with a girl and a wardrobe culminating in discovering and adventuring in another world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Lights_(novel)). :)

Comment: *The Doctor, the Widow, and the Wardrobe*, one of the Doctor Who Christmas specials, surely has to get a mention here.

Comment: Perhaps we can try a single CW answer that everyone adds to?

Comment: [snip] Stop trying to answer the question in comments :-)